# SQLException or Execute update returns null?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, exception

I am working on a java project where I have some operations in a DB.
I am working on handling the exceptions. However I am a bit confused, if a query is wrong because the parameter used doesn't exist: try to do a SELECT query with a wrong value: wrong login name, wrong order number...), does it create an SQL exception or does it simply return 0 when executeQuery or executeUpdate? And does it variate if this parameter is a primary key or a foreign key ?

Comment: If only there was a way to test that... Or just to read the documentation...

Comment: Welcome to SO. As suggested run a simple test or read the documentation. If all these fail, post your question with the what you did.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, the question can be easily answered if you would have consulted the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery-java.lang.String-

> Returns:
>   a ResultSet object that contains the data produced by the given query; never null

So if you queue for e.g. a username that doesn't exist (with this password hash), it will return a ResultSet, which will be empty though.